# How do I trigger a springframework quartz schedular job remotely or via command line for testing?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a few jobs defined inside my tomcat application that use org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean .

They are currently scheduled to run at specified time of day.  I'd like to be able to manually trigger these jobs remotely or via a command line (RMI).

Is there a way to do this (preferably with minimal setup)?  I understand I may need to set some quartz properties to allow remote invocation as well?  I tried to lookup the documentation for this but it is not clear (for me at least).

Will appreciate any hints/suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz has an extended JMX API. You can use it to run any task. 
Take a look on [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-manage-quartz-remotely) as a starting point.